# What's the equivalent of gcc's -mwindows option in cmake?

Tags: c, windows, gtk, cmake

I'm following the tuto:

http://zetcode.com/tutorials/gtktutorial/firstprograms/

It works but each time I double click on the executable,there is a console which I don't want it there.

How do I get rid of that console?

I tried this:

```
add_executable(Cmd WIN32 cmd.c)
```

But got this fatal error:

```
MSVCRTD.lib(crtexew.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _WinMain@16 referenced in function ___tmainCRTStartup
Cmd.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
```

While using gcc directly works:

```
gcc -o Cmd cmd.c -mwindows ..
```

I'm guessing it has something to do with the entry function: `int main( int argc, char *argv[])`,but why gcc works?

How can I make it work with `cmake`?

**UPDATE**

Let me paste the source code here for convenience:

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

int main( int argc, char *argv[])
{
  GtkWidget *window;

  gtk_init(&argc, &argv);

  window = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
  gtk_widget_show(window);

  gtk_main();

  return 0;
}
```

**UPDATE2**

Why `gcc -mwindows` works but `add_executable(Cmd WIN32 cmd.c)` not?

Maybe that's not the equivalent for `-mwindows` in cmake?

Answer (score 7):

add_executable(Cmd WIN32 cmd.c)

Tells CMake this is a Windows program, and it looks for WinMain instead of main. If you want to see the flags being used you can run make VERBOSE=1.   The question might be how do you define WinMain for gtk apps?  I know with Qt, you link in a library that defines it for you.

Comment: I want to achieve my goal by `cmake` without changing `main` to `WinMain`,like `gcc -mwindows` did.

Comment: cmake ..  -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS="-mwindows" for C++

Comment: Another way to do it not as part of `add_executable` is `set_target_properties(my_exe PROPERTIES WIN32_EXECUTABLE 1)`.

Comment: Thanks for the tip about verbose.  `cmake --build build_dir -v` also does the same in a generator agnostic way.

Answer (score 3):

You can set these linker flags  to have a `main()` entry point and no console:

```
SET(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS 
    "${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS} /subsystem:windows /ENTRY:mainCRTStartup")
```

For more info, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11785157/replacing-winmain-with-main-function-in-win32-programs/11785733#11785733) for the linker flags, and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11797272/774071) for how to set flags in `cmake`.

Comment: This method of specifying the entry point (can't say anything about the subsystem) didn't work for me, but `target_link_options` one suggested in https://stackoverflow.com/a/58079971/132042 did. When I looked at the flags as passed in to the linker, `/ENTRY` wasn't in there.

Answer (score 3):

For CMake 3.13 and newer you can use

```
target_link_options(target PRIVATE "/SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS" "/ENTRY:mainCRTStartup")
```

Comment: For me, it worked without double quote. Otherwise cmake will replace / with \\.

Answer (score 3):

While the accepted answer works for MinGW, it won't work for MSVC when you don't define a `WinMain`.  No answer is cross-toolchain compatible IMHO.

### Fix Subsystem

```
add_executable(my_exe WIN32 main.c)
```

basically passes `-mwindows` if MinGW compiler is used or `/SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS` if MSVC.  This sets the *subsystem* field in [PE header](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/pe-format#windows-subsystem) of the generated executable to `2` i.e. `IMAGE_SUBSYSTEM_WINDOWS_GUI`.  This instructs Windows to not provide a separate console window for this executable.

### Fix Entry Point on MSVC

When MSVC receives `/SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS`, its runtime expects<sup>1</sup> a `WinMain`, not `main`, to be defined unlike MinGW's (which works with any one defined).  If you want to continue to use `main`, fix the entry point:

```
target_link_options(my_exe PRIVATE
  $<$<CXX_COMPILER_ID:MSVC>:/ENTRY:mainCRTStartup>
)
```

<sup>1: Yes, OS first calls C runtime and [it's the C runtime which calls your executable's entry point](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49256136/183120)</sup>

### Fix Subsystem Per-config

`add_executable(my_exe WIN32 ...` internally sets the executable's [`WIN32_EXECUTABLE`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.24/prop_tgt/WIN32_EXECUTABLE.html) property.  This gives another, more useful way to do it:

```
add_executable(my_exe main.c)  # look ma, no WIN32!
set_target_properties(my_exe PROPERTIES WIN32_EXECUTABLE 1)
```

This is useful when you want to do it only for some configurations.  I personally enable this only on *Release* builds, while having a console window on *Debug* builds is useful.

```
# No console window for non-debug builds
set_target_properties(my_exe PROPERTIES WIN32_EXECUTABLE
  $<AND:$<PLATFORM_ID:Windows>,$<NOT:$<CONFIG:Debug,RelWithDebInfo>>>
)
```

### Verify

```bash
# Generate Ninja files for GCC
cmake -B build_g -G "Ninja Multi-Config"

# Generate Visual Studio project and solution for MSVC
cmake -B build_v -G "Visual Studio 17 2022"

# Build with verbosity
cmake --build build_g --config Release -v
```

This should show the actual build commands with parameters in full verbosity.  Useful to verify if `-mwindows` or `/SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS` is passed for the right build configurations.

Answer (score 2):

If you want your program to run in console mode (ie a `main` function), you have to specify it in your project's properties in MSVC. What you're using right now is a project in windowed mode (ie a `WinMain` function, which you don't have, hence the error).

But if you don't want to get the ugly console window, you want to use the windowed mode (ie transform your `main` function into a propper `WinMain` function). This way your normal window is all that will show.

edit: As an aside, you really shouldn't name your program "cmd", that's the name of Windows' command interpreter.

Comment: But I can use gcc to build a window programe with `main`,why can't `cmake`? BTW,can you elaborate what's a propper `WinMain` function? I've tried to change `main` to `WinMain` but still not working.

Comment: `int main(int, char **)` is the console version of the entry point. `int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE, HINSTANCE, LPSTR, int)` is the windowed version of the entry point.

Comment: About your first question, cmake does exactly what you tell it to do. You shouldn't ask "why can't cmake?", you should ask "why can't I tell cmake to ...?".

Answer (score 1):

According to the [CMake documentation for using the WIN32 flag with ADD_EXECUTABLE](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/cmake-2-8-docs.html#prop_tgt:WIN32_EXECUTABLE):

> When this property is set to true the executable when linked on Windows will be created with a WinMain() entry point instead of of just main().This makes it a GUI executable instead of a console application. See the CMAKE_MFC_FLAG variable documentation to configure use of MFC for WinMain executables.

However, your program's entry point is `main()` and not `WinMain()`. What you should do, instead, is omit the WIN32 flag, but you need to link against libgtk. So, you would use TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES:

```
FIND_PACKAGE(GTK2 2.6 REQUIRED gtk)
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${GTK2_INCLUDE_DIRS})
LINK_DIRECTORIES(${GTK2_LIBRARIES})
ADD_EXECUTABLE(myprogramname source1 source2 ... sourceN)
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(myprogramname ${GTK2_LIBRARIES})
```

Comment: Thanks.I've tried your 2 solutions,but none work.The first still generates a console,and the second reports: `cl : Command line warning D9002 : ignoring unknown option '-mwindows'`

Comment: @Michael Aaron Safyan, I've pasted the code above,can you take a look?

Comment: @Runner, sorry, but I don't have a copy of Windows on which to test... I am familiar with CMake, but not so much with Windows. Perhaps if you could show me documentation for the "-mwindows" flag, though, I might be able to figure out the CMake equivalent.

Comment: I'm not familiar with that flag too,but someone gives this link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fcc1zstk%28VS.71%29.aspx