# How do I tell cmake not to create a console window?

Tags: cmake

I can achieve this by gcc :

```
gcc -mwindows -o simple simple.c
```

But only find this in cmake:

```
add_executable(simple WIN32 simple.c)
```

But it's not exactly the same as `-mwindows`,

this will require the entry point to be `WinMain`,

while `gcc -mwindows` doesn't require this(can be `main`).

How should I do it properly?

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2752792/whats-the-equivalent-of-gccs-mwindows-option-in-cmake.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the equivalent of gcc's -mwindows option in cmake?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2752792/whats-the-equivalent-of-gccs-mwindows-option-in-cmake)

Answer (score 24):

If you use:

```
add_executable(simple WIN32 simple.c)
```

then you must provide a WinMain function. That's what the WIN32 flag to add_executable means: it means you're going to make it a Windows program, and provide a WinMain function.

I would recommend doing it this way if you're really writing a Windows application. It's what makes the most sense and fits most naturally with the underlying OS.

However, if you still want to pass gcc the "-mwindows" flag, but use a "main" anyway, then simply add "-mwindows" to the CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS and/or CMAKE_C_FLAGS value. You can do this in the cmake-gui program by adjusting those variables interactively to include "-mwindows" or you can do it with command line CMake, like this:

```
cmake -DCMAKE_C_FLAGS="-mwindows"
```

Comment: Just found this and it solved a very annoying problem of cmake plus a console-less windows app. In particular the desire to remove the console was made well into the project and well after the cmake magic had been weaved. THANK YOU!

Answer (score 2):

You can add target link option (for new versions of Cmake)

```
target_link_options(simple PRIVATE -mwindows)
```

https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.4.2/gcc/i386-and-x86_002d64-Windows-Options.html

Answer (score 2):

In case you need it for both Windows and Linux

```
if (WIN32)
    # /ENTRY:mainCRTStartup keeps the same "main" function instead of requiring "WinMain"
    set(SUBSYSTEM_LINKER_OPTIONS "/SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS /ENTRY:mainCRTStartup")
else()
    set(SUBSYSTEM_LINKER_OPTIONS "-mwindows")
endif()

target_link_options(TargetName PRIVATE ${SUBSYSTEM_LINKER_OPTIONS})
```

[Related Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61813042/how-to-enable-console-window-in-debug-mode-and-disable-in-release-mode-with-qt/73899308#73899308)

Answer (score 1):

As DLRdave has said saying that the executable will be a win32 one means it will have WinMain as the entry point and be a windows application.

If the application is to be cross platform still then the usual means to suppress the console window but still allow use of main is to write a stub WinMain as found in the SDL or SFML libraries which simply calls the main function with the global variables __argc and __argv as arguments and returns its result.

This prevents the application from having a console window but reduces the disruption to the code of having to use WinMain as the entry point.